# Add a column in a table to calculate the earliest date MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

**Table_name**

**column:** *[id, date1, date2, date3, date4, date5]*

(some of the values are NULL)

and I want to add a column to calculate the earliest date among date1 to date5 for each row, i.e.

**output column:** *[id, date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, earliest_date]*

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would suggest fixing your broken schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to implement it like this :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table as 
SELECT id,least(
                coalesce(date1,'2100-01-01'),
                coalesce(date2,'2100-01-01'),
                coalesce(date3,'2100-01-01'), 
                coalesce(date4,'2100-01-01')
               ) as earliestDate  
FROM mytable1;

select * from temp_table ;
Update mytable1 
     set mytable1.earliestDate =(SELECT earliestDate 
                                  from temp_table  
                                  WHERE temp_table.id=mytable1.id
                                );
select * from mytable1;
```

Change `mytable1` with your table name

Answer (score 2):

You could use LEAST coalescing the nulls to a far off future date.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
create table t (id int , d1 date,d2 date,d3 date);
    
insert into t values
  (1,'2021-01-15','2021-01-16','2021-01-13'),
  (2,null,'2021-01-22','2021-01-13');
    
select id, least(coalesce(d1,'2199-01-01'),
                 coalesce(d2,'2199-01-01'),
                 coalesce(d3,'2199-01-01'))
from t;
```